# Sudoku of alphabets solver in prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking, sudoku

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

go(Rows):- 
  foreach(J in 1..9, K in 1..9, Number = Rows[J,K], 
  Code is 0'A + Number - 1, char_code(Letter, Code), Rows[J,K] is Letter,nl)

sudoku(Rows) :-  
  append(Rows, Vs), Vs ins 1..9,
  maplist(all_distinct, Rows),
  transpose(Rows, Columns),     
  maplist(all_distinct, Columns),     
  Rows = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I],     
  blocks(A, B, C), 
  blocks(D, E, F), 
  blocks(G, H, I), 
  maplist(label, Rows),

blocks([], [], []).       
  blocks([A,B,C|Bs1], [D,E,F|Bs2], [G,H,I|Bs3]) :-     
  all_distinct([A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I]),      
  blocks(Bs1, Bs2, Bs3).
```

But this solves a sudoku containing numbers from 1 to 9 , I need to do something to convert the 1 to 9 into A to I

What I am thinking is to traverse each element in the grid and check the value accordingly replace it with the corresponding alphabet.

How can I traverse and replace the numbers or is there some better way to solve this?

Error :

[image]

Thanks! :D

Comment: Are you by any chance using a Prolog system and consulting reference material for a different Prolog system? That would explain the error.

Answer (score 1):

To convert the numbers in the `1..9` interval to letters in the `A..I` interval you can use the goal:

```
Code is 0'A + Number - 1, char_code(Letter, Code)
```

For example:

```
?- Number = 4, Code is 0'A + Number - 1, char_code(Letter, Code).
Number = 4,
Code = 68,
Letter = 'D'.
```

Assuming that the solution matrix is represented by a list of lists, the conversion can be accomplished using something like:

```
convert_matrix([], []).
convert_matrix([Row| Rows], [ConvertedRow| ConvertedRows]) :-
    convert_row(Row, ConvertedRow),
    convert_matrix(Rows, ConvertedRows).

convert_row([], []).
convert_row([Number| Numbers], [Letter| Letters]) :-
    Code is 0'A + Number - 1,
    char_code(Letter, Code),
    convert_row(Numbers, Letters).
```

But the conversion code can be simplified using `maplist` predicates. I leave that to you as an exercise. Hint: define an auxiliary predicate that takes a number and returns the corresponding letter.

Comment: And, how do I overwrite the number with its alphabetic equivalent inside the 2d matrix ?

Comment: You cannot overwrite a number. Just map the number solution into a letter solution using e.g. the `maplist` predicates or by writing the code that recursively traverses the 2d matrix. Giver it a try and edit the question with your code attempt if you get stuck.

Comment: `go(Rows):-
    foreach(J in 1..9, K in 1..9, Number = Rows[J,K], Code is 0'A + Number - 1, char_code(Letter, Code), Rows[J,K] is Letter,nl).`

Comment: Please don't write code solutions in comments. Instead, edit your original post and add the code there. Thanks.

Comment: @Paula Moura Just made the edits could you please check

Comment: Updated my answer with a portable alternative for the conversion predicate.